# Compute probability from distance-score

Tags: probability, distance, similarities, softmax

I compute Euclidian distances between a point I want to analyze and a set of points I have. I want to sort my points by decreasing "similarity".

I used to compute a "score" by inverting the distance ($s=1/d$), and use the $\cfrac{s_i}{\sum_k s_k}$ as a similarity that varies between $0$ and $1$.

I have seen that the [$softmax$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) function can also be used, the difference being that it uses $e^{1/d}$ as the score.

Which function would be closer to computing a kind of "probability"? I should apologize for probably mixing terms...

Comment: Probability of what? Both give nonnegative scores that sum to one. Neither is particularly anything like a probability. Softmax will decay quickly beyond the closest point, while the sum one will distribute scores more widely.

Comment: If you're not familiar, you might want to look at [kernels](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)#In_non-parametric_statistics).

Comment: @Dougal, thank you, your first comment answers my question ... and your second one gives me homework ;)
If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to @Dougal for his comment-answer:

> Both give nonnegative scores that sum to one. Neither is particularly anything like a probability. Softmax will decay quickly beyond the closest point, while the sum one will distribute scores more widely.

The decay part is interesting: $e^{1/x}$ is a lot bigger than $1/x$, so ${\sum_k e^x}$ will be a lot bigger than ${\sum_k 1/x}$, considering the value of $k$.

Answer (score 1):

For those still looking for different answers, I was finding individual probabilities (something like **Sigmoid**) for similarity values provided by different algorithms. This is what I am doing..
 $(1-e^{-1/x})/(1+e^{-1/x})$

Considering that similarity provides value from 0 to 1, where o being most relevant one. This has provided me with pretty good results, not sure if something like this can used for distance as well, may be taking modulus of x in above equation solves the problem.
 $(1-e^{-1/|x|})/(1+e^{-1/|x|})$

Please let me know if someone tries this.

Thanks